# Custom serialisation of a Dictionary in a DataContract

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, datacontract

Basically I have a `DataContract` which contains a `Dictionary`:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyDictionary : IDictionary<string, object> {
    [DataMember(Name = "Data")]
    protected IDictionary<string, object> Dictionary { get; private set; }

    // ...
}
```

Here is the relevent part of the XML output:

```
<Data>
 <a:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
  <a:Key>ID</a:Key>
  <a:Value i:type="s:int">2</a:Value>
 </a:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
 <a:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
  <a:Key>Value</a:Key>
  <a:Value i:type="s:int">4711</a:Value>
 </a:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
</Data>
```

How can I simplify the output to something like this here:

```
<Data>
  <ID i:type="s:int">2</ID>
  <Value i:type="s:int">4711</Value>
</Data>
```

The Dictionary key is restricted to string so if nobody get the stupid idea of using non ascii keys that should work fine. I found the attribute `CollectionDataContract` with that I come a little bit closer to what I want but the key value pairs will be saved compleate which wasts memory. Maybe it is possible to slove with the class `ISerializable` but I'm not sure if that makes some trouble with the `DataContractSerializer`. By the way the solution should also work with the `DataContractJsonSerializer`.

Comment: This wouldn't be a case of premature optimization would it?  I tend to let the DataContracts and serializers/deserializers do their own thing where ever possible to avoid headaches.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair There could be many key value pairs and also that stuff is read with a android client in a JSON format. So far I think that work should make sense.

Comment: In that case, do you want to be using JSON serializers rather than XML serializers?  If so, then perhaps sticking a JSON serializer on it and seeing its result might be worthwhile.  (perhaps it's already sufficiently optimized) Also, if you want to keep XML, you probably need to have some kind of `Entry` wrapper around ID/Value so you can have multiple KeyValuePairs.  `<Data><Entry><ID i:type="s:int">2</ID><Value i:type="s:int">4711</Value></Entry></Data>`  EDIT: Sorry, I hadn't noticed your last sentence wanting it to work with both JSON and XML serializers.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I want be able to use both XML and JSON. The JSON is not optimized too. What is the advantage of using that `Entry`s?

Comment: More of a requirement of XML (possibly JSON too).  How will you serialize multiple entries of your dictionary?  I suppose you could stack them up as `<Data><ID /><ID /><ID /><Value /><Value /><Value /></Data>` and assume that they're in the same order to properly associate ID entries with Value entries.

Comment: In MyDictionary is every key unique...

Comment: Yeah, and you'll have to express every dictionary entry as valid XML; what you have now as your desired output won't be valid for a collection of entries.  Perhaps you should edit your question to include what you expect the XML to look like for multiple entries (not just one), what the JSON currently looks like and what you want it to look like instead.  Finally, what are your concerns about this?  Are you concerned about the size of the data transfer between the services?  If so, what are you currently getting in size and what do you want/need to reduce it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having comes from the fact that IDictionary<'string, object> is (in a way) IEnumerable<'KeyValuePair<'string, object>>, and that is way the DataContractSerializer serialize each KeyValuePair individuality.

What you are asking (if I understand correctly) is to create a custom serialization, and for that you can implement the [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) interface.

Use the WriteXml, and ReadXml functions to control the xml written to the stream with the XmlWriter passed as parameter.

for example, this function

```
public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        foreach (var pair in _dictionary)
        {
            writer.WriteElementString("Key", pair.Key);
            writer.WriteElementString("Value", pair.Value.ToString());
        }
    }
```

will yield this result

```
<MyDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Sandbox">
    <Key>ID</Key>
    <Value>15</Value>
    <Key>Value</Key>
    <Value>123</Value>
</MyDictionary>
```

assuming two pairs has been entered to the dictionary (ID,15 & Value, 123).

Oh and about the JSON, there is an [IJsonSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee553175.aspx) but I never got around to working with it.

Comment: Unforchantly I got a new job and I don't use WCF anymore, but you answer is very logic and makes sense. Just for compleation could you extend your example how the `IXmlSerializable` interface has to be implemented and how it can be enfoce that this serializer is used. +1 So far for your work.